# Unit Testing Factories with nested promises in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm building an app heavy on JavaScript. I want to unit test my app using Jasmine. At this time, I'm trying to figure out how to write some code that another developer wrote. This code is a factory with some promise action in it. The code looks like the following:

```
.factory('myFactory', function ($injector, someOtherFactory) {
  return function(promise) {
    return promise.then(null, function(res) {
      if(res.result === -1) {
        promise = someOtherFactory.tryAgain('key', function another() {
          return $injector.get('$http')(response.config);
        });
      }
      return promise;
    });
  };
})
```

It's like a testing turducken. I have no idea how to test this thing. Currently, I have the following setup:

```
describe('Factory: myFactory', function () {
    it('should contain the service', inject(function (myFactory) {
        expect(myFactory).toBeDefined();
    }));
});
```

I know this isn't anything. However, I really have no idea how to test a nested promise as shown above. Any pointers?

Thanks